# ЧПУ и Yii, вывести страницу по категории

Tags: php, yii, чпу

Всем добрый вечер. Пробую знакомится с Php в целом и с Yii в частности.
В базе 2 таблицы Category и Pages. В верхнем меню сайта ссылки типа 'page/index/2' где 2 - category_id показывают список статей из выбранной категории
код при этом такой

```
public function actionIndex($id)
{
    $models = Page::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('category_id'=>$id));
    $category = Category::model()->findByPk($id);         
    $this->render('index', array('models' => $models, 'category' => $category));
}
```

Хочу сделать более понятные Url вида /page/index/about

В таблице Category есть поле url по нему и будем искать

```
public function actionIndex($url)
    {
            $category = Category::model()->findByAttributes($url);

            $id = $category->id;

            $models = Page::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('category_id'=>$id));

            $this->render('index', array('models' => $models, 'category' => $category));
    }
```

Но переход по ссылке дает ошибку 400 "Некорректный запрос"
Что происходит? Что не так?

updated:
как подсказывают в комментах попробовал посмотреть var_dump()

так вот при переходе на page/index/about все равно вываливается ошибка 400
код контроллера

```
<?php

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex($id)
{
      var_dump($url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема не решена, как-то неправильно приходит $url в контроллер. На вопрос пока забил, сделал костылями, через пару недель вернусь к этому разбирательству.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверь приходит ли правильно `$url` и `$category`. Я думаю, дело в недополученных данных

Comment: Хммм, а как?
echo пробовал в виде выводить, но до вида дело не доходит, просто "Некорректный запрос"

Когда по "category_id" выводил пустую категорию, вид вполне корректно выводил "В данной категории нет статей", а тут сразу ошибка 400

Comment: public function actionIndex($url)
{ var_dump($url);

Comment: какой-то треш вываливается в дамп, сюда не воткнуть такое
http://justpaste.it/39mz

Comment: @pustserg посмотрите, откуда приходит параметр url. Возможно, Вы перепутали и передали туда категорию вместо урла, потому как, то, что Вы вывели вар дампом - объект модели Category

Comment: Ну да точно не тот дамп показал.

Правильный дамп не дает снять. Вот код PageController.php
?php

class PageController extends Controller
{   
 public function actionIndex($url)
 {
            
            var_dump($url);
 }
}

И все равно ошибка 400 при переходе на http://localhost:8888/page/index/about

Comment: @pustserg var_dump($url);die;

Comment: Один фиг ошибка, сейчас сделал через костыли (5 actions в контроллере по чилу пунктов верхнего меню) доделаю уж проект и отдам его. Потом буду разбираться и переписывать.

Answer (score 4):

Возможно не совсем то, но я в своих проектах делаю адреса для категорий и товаров в следующем формате

```
/{название категории}
/{название категории}/{название товара}/{id товара}
```

Вот примеры: [link](http://boo.dp.ua/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8) [link](http://boo.dp.ua/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8/Skiper+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%88+%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+2B/132)

Соответственно в конфиге прописываю роуты:

```
'<category:[\w \(\)\,\.\-]+>'=>'catalog/category',
'<category:[\w \(\)\,\.\-]+>/<item:[\w \(\)\,\.\-]+>/<iid:\d+>'=>'catalog/item',
```

И в контроллере уже получаю необходимую категорию по ее названию или товар по его id.

```
public function actionCategory()
{
    $catName = Yii::app()->request->getQuery("category");
    if(empty($catName)){
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl("catalog/index"));
    }

    $category = Category::model()->find("name = :name", array("name"=>$catName));
    if(empty($category)){
        throw new CHttpException(404, "Category $catName not found");
    }

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->addCondition("cid = ".$category->cid);

    $countItems = Item::model()->count($criteria);

    $pages = new CPagination($countItems);
    $pages->route = 'catalog/category';
    $pages->pageSize = 12;
    $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

    $items = Item::model()->findAll($criteria);
    //RENDER
    $this->render("category", array(
        "category"=>$category,
        "items"=>$items,
        "pages"=>$pages,
    ));
}

public function actionItem()
{
    $iid = Yii::app()->request->getQuery("iid");
    $itemName = Yii::app()->request->getQuery("item");
    $catName = Yii::app()->request->getQuery("category");

    if(empty($iid)){
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl("catalog/index"));
    }

    $item = Item::model()->findByPk($iid);
    if(empty($item)){
        throw new CHttpException(404, "Item not found (iid=$iid)");
    }
    $item->loadAddData();
    $category = Category::model()->findByPk($item->cid);
    if(empty($category)){
        throw new CHttpException(404, "Category $catName not found");
    }

    if($itemName != $item->name || $catName != $category->name){
        $this->redirect($item->links["pageUrl"]);
    }

    //RENDER
    $this->render("item", array(
        "item"=>$item,
        "category"=>$category,
    ));
}
```

Comment: А контроллер как это обрабатывает. Тут мне кажется что-то не так с моделю Category и PageController как-то они не взаимодействуют нормально.

Comment: @pustserg отредактировал ответ, посмотрите

Comment: Насколько я вижу параметры через GET идут. А чем это лучше чем сразу action с аргументом?

Comment: @pustserg даже не задумывался об этом, изначально так приучился, теперь на автомате пишу так)

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
$category = Category::model()->findByAttributes($url);
```

Надо

```
$category = Category::model()->findByAttributes(array('url' => $url));
```